# Missing Documentation for web.config for a Node.js application on Azure Website

Tags: azure, web-config, iisnode

I'm running a Node.js server as API for my mobile app on a Windows Azure Website. And I'm having some trouble with it due to the needed web.config - but I couldn't find any really helpful documentation about it. Everything I can find is googling for specific problems on it and with a bit luck I can use the config snippets.

- is there any general documentation about the contents the web.config can contain and their meaning?
- in the start I had the problem that errors were modified by IIS to a general error. But since it's a REST API I want the HTTP status codes to be returned. I got around that with the `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` element, but it doesn't seem to work for every error.

The only documentation I found so far are example configuration files of the iisnode module.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this in the end? I'm getting "web.config not found in project, to create a project to deploy to Windows Azure you must create a Windows Azure Node.js project." when trying to deploy my node app to azure. I haven't found any documentation relating to this either.

Comment: No, I haven't found anything yet. I know some elements of the xml file a.k.a. web.config, but the separate parts of the web.config are distributed across the azure documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see the following error:

> web.config not found in project, to create a project to deploy to
>   Windows Azure you must create a Windows Azure Node.js project.

....you may have created the wrong type of Visual Studio Project.  You want a "Windows Azure Node.js Application" not a "Node.js Web Application".  The former creates a few extra files that are needed for Azure (Web.cloud.config & Web.config).

You may be able to create a dummy VS project of the correct type and then copy these files into your existing project.  Alternatively create a new project of the correct type and copy your source files into the new project.

Comment: Ok, but why isn't there any documentation about the contained values of this config? I'll mark your comment as solution, since it's the only help so far one can get :-)

Comment: Agreed.  I haven't been able to find detailed documentation either, only what can be found at [NodeJsTools](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/).  However, as the files are auto-generated hopefully you aren't blocked.  The one thing that I've had to change is iisnode path.  It defaults to "server.js" which you may not necessarily be using.

Answer (score 3):

Create Azure Basic Node.js Express Application

[image: Azure node application]